# How does Raj speak to Bernadette without problems?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory

This is regarding Raj in *The Big Bang Theory* S04 EP14, **The Thespian Catalyst**.

Raj is seen in the university canteen eating alone when Howard approaches him along with Bernadette. As we know, earlier he was unable to speak to women, but in this episode he speaks to Bernadette asking if she is going with Howard to the fellowship in the institute in Israel.

How is he able to talk to her?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not real. He is actually daydreaming in this scene and anything can happen in the dreams. He was lost in the thoughts and gets interrupted by Howard.

From the [transcript](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-4-episode-14-the-thespian-catalyst/),

> Howard (to the real Raj who is daydreaming): What ya thinking so hard about?